# Mailchimp unset a merge var via api

Tags: php, mailchimp

I have a working sync between my local DB and mail chimp. In most cases it works fine. However there is one case that doesn't seem to work.

I am updating subscribers using the [Subscribe](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php) method. With both `update_existing` and `replace_interests` set to true.

I can set merge vars via this method. However I don't seem to be able to unset them.

I have tried

- Not putting item in the array at all.
- Passing an empty string in the merge vars array for the value.
- Passing `flase` as the value.
- Passing `null` as the value.

None of which seem to affect the value at all.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is quite dated, I've found that passing an empty string **does in fact** unset a merge field.

Using the Mailchimp API to [edit a list member](https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/lists/list-members/) via `PUT` or `PATCH`:

```
{ 'FNAME': 'John', 'LNAME: '' }
```

The above will unset any previously set `LNAME`.